# MySQL update an existing table by iterating through inserted information to a different table

Tags: mysql

I'll start by indicating the fact that I'm fairly new with MySQL triggers/functions/SPs etc...
Therefore, if there is any mistake on how this question is being asked, please let me know and I'll try to get any information I missed.

### **I have the following tables:**

**aos_matchs** (MatchID eventTime   Coalition   initPlayer  initAirplane    Event   targPlayer  targAirplane    Weapon  hitCount    msgID)

**aos_players** (MatchID    Time    Era VS  Armament    Winner  redPlayers  bluePlayers)

**aos_playerslist** (Name   ace_factor)

1. aos_matchs.MatchID = aos_players.MatchID (MatchID indication)
2. aos_matchs.Initiator = aos_playerslist.Name (Linked by Player Name)
3. aos_matchs.targPlayer = aos_playerslist.Name (Linked by Player Name)

### Table Example:

**aos_matchs:**

```
 MatchID eventTime  Coalition initPlayer initAirplane Event  targPlayer targAirplane Weapon hitCount msgID
      56 00:00:00   red       Steve      Su-27        birth  none       none         none   none         1
      56 00:00:00   red       Greg       Su-27        birth  none       none         none   none         2
      56 00:00:00   blue      Gordon     F-15C        birth  none       none         none   none         3
      56 00:00:00   blue      George     F-15C        birth  none       none         none   none         4
      56 00:00:54   blue      George     F-15C        hit    Greg       Su-27        GUNS   36           5
      56 00:01:09   red       Greg       Su-27        dead   none       none         none   none         6
      56 00:01:13   red       Steve      Su-27        hit    Gordon     F-15C        GUNS   12           7
      56 00:01:38   blue      Gordon     F-15C        dead   none       none         none   none         8
      56 00:03:23   blue      George     F-15C        hit    Steve      Su-27        GUNS   10           9
      56 00:04:59   red       Steve      Su-27        hit    George     F-15C        GUNS   8           10
      56 00:05:08   blue      George     F-15C        dead   none       none         none   none        11
      74 00:00:00   red       John       F-15C        birth  none       none         none   none         1
      74 00:00:00   red       Adam       F-15C        birth  none       none         none   none         2
      74 00:00:00   red       Michael    F-15C        birth  none       none         none   none         3
      74 00:00:00   red       Bob        F-15C        birth  none       none         none   none         4
      74 00:00:00   blue      Berry      Su-27        birth  none       none         none   none         5
      74 00:00:00   blue      Jim        F-15C        birth  none       none         none   none         6
      74 00:00:00   blue      David      Su-27        birth  none       none         none   none         7
      74 00:00:00   blue      Randy      F-15C        birth  none       none         none   none         8
      74 00:00:48   red       John       F-15C        hit    Jim        F-15C        GUNS   16           9
      74 00:01:13   blue      Randy      F-15C        dead   none       none         none   none        10
      74 00:01:37   red       Adam       F-15C        hit    Jim        F-15C        GUNS   10          11
      74 00:01:46   red       John       F-15C        dead   none       none         none   none        12
      74 00:02:02   red       Bob        F-15C        dead   none       none         none   none        13
      74 00:02:09   red       Michael    F-15C        hit    David      Su-27        GUNS   52          14
      74 00:02:19   blue      David      Su-27        dead   none       none         none   none        15
      74 00:02:30   red       Adam       F-15C        hit    Berry      Su-27        F-15C  1           16
      74 00:02:30   blue      Berry      Su-27        hit    Adam       F-15C        Su-27  1           17
      74 00:02:30   red       Adam       F-15C        hit    Berry      Su-27        F-15C  1           18
      74 00:02:30   blue      Berry      Su-27        hit    Adam       F-15C        Su-27  1           19
      74 00:02:36   red       Adam       F-15C        dead   none       none         none   none        20
      74 00:03:38   red       Michael    F-15C        hit    Berry      Su-27        GUNS   48          21
      74 00:03:39   blue      Berry      Su-27        dead   none       none         none   none        22
      74 00:03:39   red       Michael    F-15C        hit    Berry      Su-27        GUNS   10          23
      74 00:15:09   blue      Jim        F-15C        hit    Michael    F-15C        GUNS   40          24
      74 00:15:18   red       Michael    F-15C        dead   none       none         none   none        25
```

**aos_players:**

```
MatchID Time                Era     VS      Armament    Winner  redPlayers  bluePlayers
56      0000-00-00 00:00:00 modern  2vs2    GUNS        red     Steve/Greg  Gordon/George
74      0000-00-00 00:00:00 modern  4vs4    GUNS        blue    Adam/John/Michael/Bob   Berry/Jim/David/Randy
```

**Players**

```
Name    ace_factor
Steve   1
John    1
Adam    1
Michael 1
David   1
Bob     1
Randy   1
Gordon  1
George  1
Greg    1
```

I would like to catch with a trigger any information that is being inserted to Match table then run a query to get relative info from MatchInfo table and iterate through the query results.
Upon going through row by row, deciding what will be the update to the Players table subsequently.

What I thought to do is -

1. Create a trigger that will catch insert operations to match table after the info is inserted.
2. In that trigger, run the query on the relative MatchInfo table and then go through each row of the query result and update the Players table accordingly.

Appreciate any help with a trigger example that will do the above.

Edit: by Barmars request, I edited the table to the original layout with some original information for better understanding.

The aos_playerslist is updating with the following trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `mytable`$$

DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `UpdatePlayersList`$$

CREATE
    /*!50017 DEFINER = 'admin'@'%' */
    TRIGGER `UpdatePlayersList` BEFORE INSERT ON `aos_matchs` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN  
INSERT IGNORE INTO `aos_playerslist` (`name`,`ace_factor`) VALUES (new.initplayer,1);
END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Next I would like to update the ace_factor in the aos_playerslist table whenever a new match is inserted into the aos_matchs table, when that happens, I'm trying to get a trigger working that will update by the following query results -

```
SELECT t1.initPlayer,t1.percentage/t2.full_percentage AS 'kill_percent'
            FROM (
                SELECT aos_matchs.MatchID,aos_matchs.`initPlayer`,SUM(CASE aos_matchs.Weapon
                WHEN 'GUNS' THEN aos_matchs.hitcount
                ELSE 70
                END) AS 'percentage',dtable.dead
                FROM aos_matchs
                LEFT JOIN (
                    SELECT MatchID,initPlayer AS dead
                    FROM aos_matchs
                    WHERE `event`='dead') dTable
                ON dTable.MatchID=aos_matchs.`MatchID` AND dTable.dead=aos_matchs.targPlayer
                WHERE aos_matchs.`Event`='hit' 
                AND dTable.dead IS NOT NULL
                GROUP BY aos_matchs.`MatchID`,aos_matchs.`initPlayer`,dtable.dead) t1
            LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT aos_matchs.MatchID,SUM(CASE aos_matchs.Weapon
                WHEN 'GUNS' THEN aos_matchs.hitcount
                ELSE 70
                END) AS 'full_percentage',dtable.dead
                FROM aos_matchs
                LEFT JOIN (
                    SELECT MatchID,initPlayer AS dead
                    FROM aos_matchs
                    WHERE `event`='dead') dTable
                ON dTable.MatchID=aos_matchs.`MatchID` AND dTable.dead=aos_matchs.targPlayer
                WHERE aos_matchs.`Event`='hit' 
                AND dTable.dead IS NOT NULL
                GROUP BY aos_matchs.`MatchID`,dtable.dead) t2
            ON t1.MatchID=t2.MatchID 
            AND t1.dead=t2.dead
            WHERE t1.MatchID = <matchID>
            AND t1.dead = <the tested dead player>
```

Then, by the dead tested player and the kill percentage of the killer, it will update the ace_factor column by these rules -

```
if ace_factor1==ace_factor2 then
{
    if player_1 wins
    {
        new_acefactor1=ace_factor1+(ace_factor1/(ace_factor1+ace_factor2));
        new_acefactor2=ace_factor2-(ace_factor1/(ace_factor1+ace_factor2));
    }
    else if player_2 wins
    {
        new_acefactor1=ace_factor1-(ace_factor1/(ace_factor1+ace_factor2));
        new_acefactor2=ace_factor2+(ace_factor1/(ace_factor1+ace_factor2));
    }
}

else if ace_factor1>ace_factor2 then
{
/*Case 2a: the stronger player (player 1) wins the weaker (player 2)
/* then the change in the ace factor of the two opponents is determined by the ace factor of 
/*the weaker player
    if player_1 wins then
    {
        new_acefactor1=ace_factor1+(ace_factor2/(ace_factor1+ace_factor2));
        /*if the ace factor of player 2 (loser) equals "1" then it remains "1" (no 
        /*reduction)
        if ace_factor2==1 then 
        new_acefactor2=ace_factor2;
        else 
        /* if ace factor of player 2 is greater than "1" then it is reduced
        new_acefactor2=ace_factor2-(ace_factor2/(ace_factor1+ace_factor2));
    }


    /* Case 2b: the weaker player (player 2) wins the stronger player (player 1)

    else 
    {
    /* in that case the new ace factor of the weaker player (winner) is determined 
    /*(increased) by the value of the ace factor of his (stronger) opponent (loser)
        new_acefactor2=ace_factor2+(ace_factor1/(ace_factor1+ace_factor2));

    /* in that case the new ace factor of the stronger player (loser) is determined 
    /*(reduced) by the DIFFERENCE between the two ace factors 
    new_acefactor1=ace_factor1-((ace_factor1-ace_factor2)/(ace_factor1+ace_factor2));
    }
```

I hope this is clear enough, I'm just looking for a trigger that will fetch the query results for each dead player and allow the update of the ace_factor column correctly according to the above rules.

Here is the trigger I've been trying, but it's not working as I probably did something wrong as I'm new to triggers all together:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `mytable`$$

CREATE
    TRIGGER `UpdateAceFactor` AFTER INSERT ON `aos_players`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE mPlayers (pName VARCHAR(255));
    SET @cid =0;
    SET @mID = new.MatchID;

    INSERT INTO mPlayers
    SELECT initPlayer
    FROM aos_matchs
    WHERE MatchID = @mID
    AND `event`='dead';

    WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mPlayers WHERE processed = 0)>0 DO
        SELECT Top 1 @cid = id FROM mPlayers WHERE processed = 0;
            DECLARE initP VARCHAR(255);
            DECLARE initPace INT;
            DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR (
            SELECT t1.initPlayer,t1.percentage/t2.full_percentage AS 'kill_percent'
            FROM (
                SELECT aos_matchs.MatchID,aos_matchs.`initPlayer`,SUM(CASE aos_matchs.Weapon
                WHEN 'GUNS' THEN aos_matchs.hitcount
                ELSE 70
                END) AS 'percentage',dtable.dead
                FROM aos_matchs
                LEFT JOIN (
                    SELECT MatchID,initPlayer AS dead
                    FROM aos_matchs
                    WHERE `event`='dead') dTable
                ON dTable.MatchID=aos_matchs.`MatchID` AND dTable.dead=aos_matchs.targPlayer
                WHERE aos_matchs.`Event`='hit' 
                AND dTable.dead IS NOT NULL
                GROUP BY aos_matchs.`MatchID`,aos_matchs.`initPlayer`,dtable.dead) t1
            LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT aos_matchs.MatchID,SUM(CASE aos_matchs.Weapon
                WHEN 'GUNS' THEN aos_matchs.hitcount
                ELSE 70
                END) AS 'full_percentage',dtable.dead
                FROM aos_matchs
                LEFT JOIN (
                    SELECT MatchID,initPlayer AS dead
                    FROM aos_matchs
                    WHERE `event`='dead') dTable
                ON dTable.MatchID=aos_matchs.`MatchID` AND dTable.dead=aos_matchs.targPlayer
                WHERE aos_matchs.`Event`='hit' 
                AND dTable.dead IS NOT NULL
                GROUP BY aos_matchs.`MatchID`,dtable.dead) t2
            ON t1.MatchID=t2.MatchID 
            AND t1.dead=t2.dead
            WHERE t1.MatchID = @mID
            AND t1.dead = @cid) kTable;

            DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

            OPEN cur1;

            the_loop: LOOP

                FETCH cur1 INTO initP,initPace;
                IF done THEN
                    LEAVE the_loop;
                END IF;

                IF initPace == (SELECT ace_factor FROM `aos_playerslist` WHERE `Name`=@cid) THEN
                    UPDATE `aos_playerslist`
                    SET ace_factor = (initPace+(initPace/initPace+(SELECT ace_factor FROM `aos_playerslist` WHERE `Name`=@cid)));
                    WHERE `name`=initP;

                    IF (SELECT ace_factor FROM `aos_playerslist` WHERE `Name`=@cid) > 1 THEN
                        UPDATE `aos_playerslist`
                        SET ace_factor = ((SELECT ace_factor FROM `aos_playerslist` WHERE `Name`=@cid)-(initPace/initPace+(SELECT ace_factor FROM `aos_playerslist` WHERE `Name`=@cid)));
                        WHERE `name`=@cid;
                    END IF;
                END IF;

                IF initPace > (SELECT ace_factor FROM `aos_playerslist` WHERE `Name`=@cid) THEN
                    UPDATE `aos_playerslist`
                    SET ace_factor = (initPace+(initPace/initPace+(SELECT ace_factor FROM `aos_playerslist` WHERE `Name`=@cid)));
                    WHERE `name`=initP;

                    IF (SELECT ace_factor FROM `aos_playerslist` WHERE `Name`=@cid) > 1 THEN
                        UPDATE `aos_playerslist`
                        SET ace_factor = ((SELECT ace_factor FROM `aos_playerslist` WHERE `Name`=@cid)-(initPace/initPace+(SELECT ace_factor FROM `aos_playerslist` WHERE `Name`=@cid)));
                        WHERE `name`=@cid;
                    END IF;
                END IF;

                IF initPace < (SELECT ace_factor FROM `aos_playerslist` WHERE `Name`=@cid) THEN
                    UPDATE `aos_playerslist`
                    SET ace_factor = (initPace+((SELECT ace_factor FROM `aos_playerslist` WHERE `Name`=@cid)/(initPace+(SELECT ace_factor FROM `aos_playerslist` WHERE `Name`=@cid))));
                    WHERE `name`=initP;

                    UPDATE `aos_playerslist`
                    SET ace_factor = ((SELECT ace_factor FROM `aos_playerslist` WHERE `Name`=@cid)-((initPace-(SELECT ace_factor FROM `aos_playerslist` WHERE `Name`=@cid))/initPace+(SELECT ace_factor FROM `aos_playerslist` WHERE `Name`=@cid)));
                    WHERE `name`=@cid;
                END IF;

            END LOOP the_loop;
            CLOSE cur1;

        UPDATE mPlayers SET processed = 1 WHERE id = @cid
        END;
    END;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Just write the `UPDATE` statement as you would do it by hand. Once you get it working, put it in a `CREATE TRIGGER` statement.

Comment: If you want more specific help, you need to be more specific about what you want to update.

Comment: It's not obvious from your example how the values in the `Players` table is generated from the data in the `Match` and `MatchInfo` tables.

Comment: The values in the Players table are generated through a different trigger that finds the player name in any matchinfo table and adds it to the players table if it isn't already there, it also adds 1 value to the factor column.

The operation I need to do in the factor column in the players table is with a specific query that checks the value of the adversary player first from the players table.

Comment: You need to explain in the question what you're trying to do with this trigger.

Comment: Stop talking in generalities like "a specific query". Explain precisely what you're trying to do, show the query. Also show your attempted solution to the problem -- we're not here to do your work for you, we want to help you fix your code that doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, although I'm not sure why it is needed, I just need the structure that I explained because I can't get the trigger working.

Example of query to run after catching the insert operation - 


`select initiator,sum(hits)
from MatchInfo
where MatchID = @matchIDfromMatchTable
group by initiator`

Iterate through all the rows of this result and then run IF statements to check if the hits the players have, are less then/more then/equal the players factor in the factor table, in each case there would be a different operation to do on the factor number in the players table.

Comment: What structure did you explain? I don't see anything about it in a question. Stop writing comments and edit the question. Add specific examples.

Comment: You don't iterate in SQL. Use a `JOIN` to get row from one table that matches another table.

Comment: And in a trigger, you can use `NEW.matchID` to get the column from the row that was inserted.

Comment: My problem with the trigger is not getting the MatchID, the problem is getting the values back after running the above query, and then going through each row of those results, I tried using cursors, but unfortunately it did not work, probably because of a syntax/structure error, that's why I wrote here, to get assistance with the structure for such a procedure.

Comment: I suspect you're going about this all wrong, but since you haven't posted any code it's impossible to tell.  I would show you the correct way to do it, but I can't figure out what you're trying to do. Why won't you add these details to the question like I keep asking you?

Comment: Updated with the whole info, I hope it will be more clear now.

Comment: What are `ace_factor1` and `ace_factor2`? There's just a single `ace_factor` column in the `Players` table.

Comment: ace_factor1 and ace_factor2 are examples for the comparison between the first player ace_factor and the second players ace_factor.

Comment: FYI: There's no `SELECT TOP 1` in MySQL, you have to use `SELECT ... ORDER BY column LIMIT 1`.

Comment: Ok,  instead of giving a million comments,  do you have a solution?

Comment: No, I don't. I'm totally lost in your code, it's just too complex for me when I don't understand the application.

Comment: Ok,  that is exactly why I didn't want to put the whole info,  just the relevant part that will indicate what kind of trigger I want and can't create.

Comment: The issue is that if it weren't so complicated, the answer would be to use an `UPDATE` with a `JOIN`. I started trying to write that kind of answer, but when I saw your code I realized that it wouldn't work. The details are important.

Comment: The thing is that the update would need to rely on each line that the query returns. That's what I'm having issues with. I'll have to see if there is any other way. Maybe insert into the sql with the numbers calculated beforehand, which would be a lot less convenient.